# expect().toThrow() not working when running tests

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I have the following test for a service in Angular4:

```
it('should throw an error when given an invalid Batch ID',
    async(inject([EventLogService, HttpTestingController],
      (service: EventLogService, backend: HttpTestingController) => {
        const batchId = "nope";

        expect(function() {
          service.getEvents(batchId).subscribe();
        }).toThrow();

        backend
          .expectOne(service.createUrl(EVENTS_URL, batchId, EVENTS_ENDPOINT));
      }))
);
```

The `expect().toThrow()` isn't working even though if I run the app and give it a `batchId` of `"nope"`, there is an error thrown. In other words, the test is passing even though it should be failing.

This is what the service function looks like:

```
public getEvents(batchId: string): Observable<EventLogModel[]> {
    let url = this.createUrl(EVENTS_URL, batchId, EVENTS_ENDPOINT);

    return this.httpClient.get(url)
      .map((res: any) => {
        const events = res.eventList;
        return events.map((e) => new EventLogModel(e));
      })
      .catch(this.handleError);
}

private handleError(error: Response | any) {
  console.error(error.message || error);
  return Observable.throw(error.message || error);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:**

I've tried the following:

```
  it('should throw an error when given an invalid Batch ID',
    fakeAsync(inject([EventLogService, HttpTestingController],
      async (service: EventLogService, backend: HttpTestingController) => {
        const batchId = "nope";

        const err =
          await service.getEvents(batchId).toPromise()
            .then(() => { throw new Error('Unexpected') })
            .catch(err => err);

        expect(err).toEqual(jasmine.any(Error));

        //Expected no open requests, found one ERROR
        backend
          .expectOne(service.createUrl(EVENTS_URL, batchId, EVENTS_ENDPOINT));
      }))
  );
```

but get the test failing saying `Error: Expected no open requests, found 1` even though I explicitly say `.expectOne()`.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because `toThrow` expects a function that will throw an error. While `service.getEvents` returns an observable of an error, and it should be tested accordingly. For example, an observable can be converted to a promise and be tested with `async..await`:

```
it('should throw an error when given an invalid Batch ID',
    fakeAsync(inject([EventLogService, HttpTestingController],
      async (service: EventLogService, backend: HttpTestingController) => {
        ...
        const err = await service.getEvents(batchId).toPromise()
        .then(() => { throw new Error('Unexpected') })
        .catch(err => err);

        expect(err).toEqual(jasmine.any(Error));
        ...
      }))
);
```

Since the spec mocks a request, it can be safely changed from `async` to `fakeAsync`.

Comment: I updated my OP with an attempt at what you suggested. I'm getting a new error now. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This post explains that the toThrow() fails because it's trying to invoke the method.

https://ajsblackbelt.wordpress.com/2014/05/18/jasmine-tests-expect-tothrow/comment-page-1/

The author goes on to explain this in detail.  They suggest that you may be able to write: `expect(service.method).toThrow()` instead.

This worked for me, since my method has no parameters.  For a method with parameters, I'd suggest reading the post for the detail.